# Short way of adding a listener?

Tags: optimization, listener, javafx-2

In JavaFX, if I want a non-anonymous method to be called on a property change and I don't need all those informations like old value and new value, is there a shorter way than

```
rb.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
        onSomethingChanged();
    }           
});
```

I think in C# it was something like

```
rb.selectedProperty()+=onSomethingChanged();
```

Is there something similar in JavaFX / Java? Something that is shorter than the first code sample? Or is it possible to write some kind of helper functions for this?

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Try to look here : http://sett.ociweb.com/sett/settFeb2013.html but it works only with java 8

Comment: here is example of using java 8 lambdas with javfx http://learnjavafx.typepad.com/weblog/2013/02/mary-had-a-little-%CE%BB.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no shorter notation in JDKs up to 7.

When JDK8 with Lambda project will be released it would be possible to write next:

```
rb.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, oldV, newV) -> onSomethingChanged());
```